# Ubuntu installer doesn't recognize Windows 10 in SSD

Tags: windows, ssd

I have this scene:

- An SSD of 500GB with Windows 10 installed inside.
- An Hard disk of 1TB which I have partitioned in 500GB for data and 500GB remaining free for Ubuntu 20

When I try to install Ubuntu using a USB bootable disk, the installer doesn't recognize Windows.

I have already set to AHCI the harddisk. I have already disabled the fast start up of windows too. The problem remains.

I tried this too:

https://www.techsupportpk.com/2020/04/how-to-fix-ubuntu-not-detecting-windows.html

Summarizing, into a Live Ubuntu session, after recognizing the Windows partitions and cleanning it of bad sectors:

```
$ lsblk
$ sudo fsck -y /dev/sdb1
$ sudo fsck -y /dev/sdb2
...
```

the tutorial author ainms to install os-prober and update grub:

```
$ sudo apt -y install os-prober
$ sudo update-grub
```

Here I get this error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo update-grub
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of «/cow».
```

And when I commented it, the author ainmed me to mount a 'fake linux' in my Windows 10 partition using:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
sudo chroot /mnt
```

But in this point I get an error like "...it couldn't found bin/bash directory"

A problem after other... I really don't know why I can't install Ubuntu beside Windows just like the rest humans of this world. My PC is an ASUS TUF Gaming FX505. Do you have any idea to help me?

Comment: Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? And Windows updates turn fast start up back on, so did Windows update? COW is copy on write or you tried to run an update on the live installer which is not writable.  The sudo update-grub is to be run inside your install.

Comment: @AliRojas same issue here, did you find any solution?

Comment: @Bital I could solve the problem changing the 1st boot option of the PC, I don't remember exactly which one: the one that has already Windows, or the other where I wanted install Ubuntu. Probe both.